# Can I make the Quarter function Query "wrap" so that it understands that Q1-1=4?

Tags: switch-statement, google-sheets-formula

I would like to display previous quarter vs current quarter data. However as a school district we operate on a Q3, Q4, Q1, Q2 sequence.

I have a query using Quarter that pulls the 2 correct sets of data except for this sequencing issue. Is there a way I can use SWITCH inside the query to "redirect" Q1-1 to 4 instead of 0?

[Copy of Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19kwU7yS0_dVGqkFKkDzuHYCn0rs0UPuPEHmslq2peIY/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is my formula that queries data on the Form sheet into a count (formula is locating in Data!W2):

=counta(iferror(Query(Form!$A$2:$J, "select Col1 where (Col5 matches '"&$A2&"' OR Col6 matches '"&$A2&"' OR Col7 matches '"&$A2&"' OR Col8 matches '"&$A2&"' OR Col9 matches '"&$A2&"' OR Col10 matches '"&$A2&"') AND Quarter(Col4)=Quarter(Now())-1")))

I tried to figure out using an IF to resolve the issue and tried using SWITCH, but both kept returning 0 for the count.

What I want is for Quarter(Now())-1 to be "redirected" to the value 4 instead of 0 when Quarter(Now()) is returning 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Here's one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19kwU7yS0_dVGqkFKkDzuHYCn0rs0UPuPEHmslq2peIY/edit#gid=1024238048) you may improvise on. I've created a virtual 5th column in the test scenario here which outputs the quarter of the specified date(from Column_D) & then switches ONLY the `4` to `0`*

```js
=query({A2:D,let(Σ,index(if(len(D2:D),roundup(month(D2:D)/3,0),)),switch(Σ,4,0,Σ))},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 Where Col5="&1-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! To implement it with my existing query, do I need to add the first part {  {A2:D,let(Σ,index(if(len(D2:D),roundup(month(D2:D)/3,0),)),switch(Σ,4,0,Σ))}  ] before the select in my query?

Comment: Instead of hardcoding it directly inside query, I added it as an extra column_K for you to get an idea of what it does actually.

Comment: I'm not sure I was clear in my question. When my query calculates Quarter -1 to identify the previous quarter I'm running into the problem that for Q1, that returns a zero. Because quarter 0 isn't a valid value, I am getting no results from the query when the previous query is Q4. This means that next quarter (Quarter 1) I won't have any previous quarter data that I can display.

Comment: In the test formula above I used `1-1` at the end to simulate a `Quarter=0` situation. Ideally `1-1` would be `Quarter(Col4)=Quarter(Now())-1`

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are doing (way more advanced that my basic skills/knowledge)  but I feel like the output is the opposite of what I need. I want zeroes from (quarter(Now())-1) to turned into Quarter 4s. Your switch column has zeroes but no 4s, I need it to do the opposite, please.

Comment: Lets put aside the switch/0/4 thing... When you are in quarter 1 you want your formula `Quarter(Col4)=Quarter(Now())-1` to pull **quarter 4** months (Oct, Nov, Dec) right?!

Comment: Yes please, that's correct. I need Q1 data in one column (Qnow) and q4 data in the other (Qprev)